# How to change programmatically exposed filters in views

Tags: 7, views

I have a page view with exposed filters. One of the filters is term vocabulary, and that's dropdown list, user can select only one category (term).

I want to set programmatically one term from dropdown list when I came from specific URL. I tried with `views_query_alter` where `$category` is `tid`.

```
 $set_exposed_input  = array();
 $set_exposed_input['field_category_tid'] = $category;

 if ($set_exposed_input) {
    $view->set_exposed_input($set_exposed_input);
 }
```

Comment: Here is also usefull link: https://groups.drupal.org/node/82219#comment-1116663

Comment: dupe http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26431/add-filter-criteria-in-views-programmatically

Answer (score 15):

For drupal 7 you can use

```
$view->exposed_input[$key] = $value;
```

This is

```
$view->exposed_input['title'] = 'My title is a cat';
```

For a full example you can try this:

```
$name = 'name_of_view';
$display = 'page_1';
$alter = array('exposed' =>array('title' => 'title_value'));

$view = views_get_view($name);
$view->init_display($display);
$view->preview=TRUE;
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;


if(isset($alter['exposed'])){
  foreach($alter['exposed'] as $key => $valor){

     $view->exposed_input[$key] = $valor;

  }
}

$view->pre_execute();
$output = $view->display_handler->preview();
$view->post_execute();

print_r($view->result);
```

Other way is using the views set_option function

```
$filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');

foreach($alter['exposed'] as $key => $valor){
   $filters[$key]['value'] = $valor;
   $view->display_handler->set_option('filters', $filters);
}
```

Comment: where do you place this, in a view pre execute or something like that?

Comment: In the views tpl!  And the full example, wherever, it has a load view function

Comment: You can also add it to hook_views_pre_view

Comment: The tpl file should be used to display rendered content, not to set business logic. Please try one of the other myriad views hooks: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/7

Comment: What about non exposed filter? I have very rare use case and I need to set filter value by custom code.

Comment: I have found solution: https://groups.drupal.org/node/113684#comment-1071468

Answer (score 2):

with Drupal 7.54 when you want to process the exposed filter programmatically, this is how you do it when you have a multiple valued field.
The solution to see how to pass exposed filter is to follow how the URL is made.

Here: view_name?alias[1]=1

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->init_display('display_id');

$filters = array('alias' => array('1'));
$view->set_exposed_input($filters);

$view->execute();
```

You can execute this from wherever you want. Preferably from the module file.

Answer (score 1):

Set exposed filter value like this:

```
$view->exposed_input['field_category_tid'] = $category;
```