# Creating a filter programatically with views_get_view

Tags: entities, views

I have a lot of views and I want to add a filter to just one of them. This view is called **soccer_news_feed** and I want it to check out my custom field: **field_data_field_is_score** and display if it's not 1.

So in a hook_update_n I have this code:

```
$view = views_get_view("soccer_news_feed");

$view->add_item(
  $view->current_display,
  'filter',
  'field_data_field_is_score',
  'field_is_score_value',
  array('operator' => '<>','value' => array('value' => 1))
);
```

So I thought maybe this work but I get this error when I run updb:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_option() on a non-object in /var/www/public/sites/all/modules/contrib/views/includes/view.inc on line 2450
```

I'm very lost on this.

Comment: What version of Views are you using here? I'm guessing 7.x-3.j I can't answer based on the info supplied, but if we know what's in `views/includes/view.inc`, we've gone a long way towards answering this.

Comment: I think your question was previously answered in another similar question. Please check it out. You might need to have a exposed filter set out in your view. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/how-to-change-programmatically-exposed-filters-in-views/49480#49480 Hope this helps! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The first key to enlightenment is to at error message.  It says the fatal error happened in views/includes/view.in, around line line 2450. I don't know your exact version, but in one of my Drupal 7 installs, here's what's close to line 2450:

```
  /**
   * Add an item with a handler to the view.
   *
   * These items may be fields, filters, sort criteria, or arguments.
   */
  function add_item($display_id, $type, $table, $field, $options = array(), $id = NULL) {
    $types = views_object_types();
    $this->set_display($display_id);

    $fields = $this->display[$display_id]->handler->get_option($types[$type]['plural']);
```

My line numbers don't match in my version, but notice the last line of the excerpt.  Best guess that $this->display[$display_id]->handler ($this is your view) is either NULL, or is not an object.

$this->display is an array of view_display objects; and $this->display($display_id) should either be a view_display, or perhaps, NULL or FALSE.

I'd recommend trying the following to debug this:

- First, perhaps it's possible that $view->current_display is not initialized, or isn't what you think it is. Try substituting it with 'default', which usually works with Views.
- If you look at your view's definition and know the machine ID of one of your displays for that view (say, 'page_1'), try substituting that and see if it works.
- If you're using an IDE with a source debugger, this is a good time to learn to use it a bit. Views can be pretty opaque as to what it's doing under the hood, and sometimes, seeing what the data actually is in real time can save you a lot of time.

That's as much as I can suggest w/o knowing the exact version of Views you're using, but it may get you started.

Good luck, in any case.