# Add conditional redirect to Views exposed filter (using BEF)

Tags: 7, views

I have a view showing a select list of locations. Upon selecting a location the View shows a Google Map with the locations of the current selection.

For certain items in the select list I would like to redirect away from the View to another page.

I have looked at these discussions:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1379492#comment-6273188

[How to change programmatically exposed filters in views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/how-to-change-programmatically-exposed-filters-in-views)

But none of them mentions my specific case of conditional redirection.

Any clues very welcome!

Comment: Hey @benjamin_dk. For some of the values of the Select (exposed filter) you want to have a simple redirect, instead of the filter actually interacting with the (Google Map) view. Is that right? Have you thought of using a javascript approach? Are the filter changes auto-submitted in your view at the moment?

Comment: Yes I just want a simple redirect and the form is autosubmitting. And yea at the moment I have a crude  javascript function redirecting but this causes a brief flash of the unwanted view to be shown first.

Comment: FYI, I updated my answer below with a switch statement that focuses on your OP even more. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A sketch of an idea, for prototyping.
Once this works for you, you could move this javascript code into a render array via form alter. Here are some links for that:

- https://api.drupal.org/comment/31448#comment-31448
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached

Prototyping: Inside the header area of your view you can insert a js snippet inside of a 'Global: Text area' field (use the full html text format to avoid stripping of html tags):

[image]

And here is an example snippet to get you started, I am targeting the node's status exposed filter from my sample view:

```
<script>
(function($) {
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#edit-status').change(function() {
      switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'optionA':
          window.location = "https://www.drupal.org";            
          break;
        case 'optionB':
        case 'optionC':
          // grouping option together if they have the same target url
          window.location = "https://petrakis.design";            
          break;
        default:
          // default code block, simply exit
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not fix the problem. Views still shows the filtered content for a moment before redirecting.

Comment: Your suggestions are valid in the sense that it adds the javascript to the form. Unfortunately these methods do not fix the problem. I tried both adding js in the 'Global: Text Area' and as attached element to the views exposed filter form. I shifted the js to the beginning of the attached js array. I don't know if it is relevant, but the filtered content is in an attachment. Completely removing the autosubmit.js file (ctools) does not work either, since I need the filter parameters from the URL in my redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative answer, not javascript based and much closer to the "best practices" way.

The most important piece of information lies inside the ctools/js/auto-submit.js file of CTools. This is the verbatim comment in the beginning of that file:

> To make a form auto submit, all you have to do is 3 things:
>    ctools_add_js('auto-submit');
>
> On gadgets you want to auto-submit when changed, add the ctools-auto-submit
>    class. With FAPI, add:
>
> '#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-auto-submit')),
>
> If you want to have auto-submit for every form element,
>    add the ctools-auto-submit-full-form to the form. With FAPI, add:
>
> '#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-auto-submit-  full-form')),
>
> If you want to exclude a field from the ctool-auto-submit-full-form auto submission,
>    add the class ctools-auto-submit-exclude to the form element. With FAPI, add:
>
> '#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-auto-submit-exclude')),
>
> Finally, you have to identify which button you want clicked for autosubmit.
>    The behavior of this button will be honored if it's ajaxy or not:
>
> '#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-use-ajax', 'ctools-auto-submit-click')),
>
> Currently only 'select', 'radio', 'checkbox' and 'textfield' types are supported. We probably
>    could use additional support for HTML5 input types.

Following that, you need to implement a custom module and using _form_alter:

1. Disable auto-submit for your exposed filter using the 'ctools-auto-submit-exclude' class
2. Attach a javascript that will do something similar to the alternative answer's javascript, namely, redirect to another url.

In the following example code, I use a simple redirect based on an exposed filter of the basic content types, article and page. Tested and it worked!

A sample form_alter implementation:

```
function somemodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // This is the name of the FAPI exposed filter element
  $filter_exposed_select_name = 'type';

  // This is the name of the select values and their respective target url
  $target_urls = array(
    'page' => 'http://www.drupal.org',
    'article' => 'http://drupal.stackexchange.com'
  );


  // This will disable auto-submitting the form for our filter element
  $form[$filter_exposed_select_name]['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('ctools-auto-submit-exclude'));

  // This will attach a javascript to the element for handling the redirects
  $form[$filter_exposed_select_name]['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'somemodule') . '/somemodule.js';
  $form[$filter_exposed_select_name]['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'data' => array(
      'bef_custom_redirect' => array(
        'target_name' => $filter_exposed_select_name,
        'target_urls' => $target_urls,
      )
    ),
    'type' => 'setting'
  );
}
```

and the accompanying javascript file (somemodule.js).

```
(function($){

Drupal.behaviors.BEFCustomRedirect = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('.ctools-auto-submit-exclude.form-select[name=' + settings.bef_custom_redirect.target_name + ']').change(function() {
      window.location = settings.bef_custom_redirect.target_urls[$(this).val()];
    });
  }
}

})(jQuery);
```

Hope this does the trick for you, let me know how it went!