# Filtering exposed filters with views_get_view_result() function

Tags: views

I have built a module so that I can display PDFs with phpwkhtmltopdf. I am currently calling my view data using:

```
$view = views_get_view_result('course_catalog');
```

My question is, is there a way to have filter my exposed filters with this function? If not, what is the best way to go about this? --I suppose I could manually filter through the results with PHP, but that hardly seems efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `views_get_view_result` does not allow setting filters: https://www.drupal.org/node/1428696

Instead of using `views_get_view_result`, you might try with other functions of the Views API:

```
$view = views_get_view('course_catalog');
$view->set_exposed_input($my_exposed_input);
$view->init_display();
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$result = $view->result;
```

You can check the documentation for the [set_exposed_input](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aset_exposed_input/7.x-3.x) method, and also this related Drupal Answers question, for alternatives: [How to change programmatically exposed filters in views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/how-to-change-programmatically-exposed-filters-in-views)

Comment: As the documentation is a bit short, I'd add that `$my_exposed_input` should be of the form `array("my_filter_label_1" => some_value, etc.)`.