# How can I allow a filter in a view to be modified by a site admin without granting full permission to alter the view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a module with a view and some other functionality. I want to give site managers the ability to change the filter on the view (this isn't an exposed filter) but not give access to change the view.  I know how to make a form for the module but what would I use to get the information from the view and return the information.  I assume it is one of these:  https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7.x-3.x

Comment: Is this a reason you can't use an exposed filter?  Allowing changes to the filter but not the rest of the view is the specific use case of exposed filters.

Comment: It is a one page view that is meant to just show all the content of a site but a site admin can decide if it shows all or some content.   They don't want anon users seeing all the content (media and such).

Comment: Duplicate of [Add FILTER CRITERIA in Views Programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26431/add-filter-criteria-in-views-programmatically) Personally, I wouldn't use the accepted answer. Go with Rix's (which programmatically prints the view) or Duncanmoo's answer (which uses hook to alter the filter).